# C# Why is the sizeof(constant) not defined

Tags: c#, constants, sizeof

Im sorry i just wrote something to get my point accross.

Here is an actual example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CacheScratch
{
    class Class1
    {
        public const int a = 0xABAC;

        int test()
        {
            return sizeof(a);
        }
    }
}
```

If i have a const, why do i get the error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0233  'a' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context (consider using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf)

Why do I need a Marshal for a fixed size variable?

Comment: Your code isn't close to compiling. You're referencing a non-existing variable, you're not using a type argument and `0xA4B4` doesn't fit in a short.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: sizeof takes a type in C#, not an arbitrary expression.

Comment: There's really no reason you would even need to know this in .Net because it is managed code.

Comment: The size of an int is always 4 in C#.  But why do you care what the size is?  **Say what problem you are actually trying to solve here**. Odds are pretty good you're doing something wrong if you're trying to take the size of an integer in C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sizeof() structures not known. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048540/sizeof-structures-not-known-why)

Comment: @EricLippert I updated the question.

Comment: This is now a completely different question. Please don't do that. Delete the question and start an entirely new question if you have a completely different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN: sizeof (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)

> For all other types, including structs, the sizeof operator can be
> used only in unsafe code blocks. Although you can use the
> Marshal.SizeOf method, the value returned by this method is not always
> the same as the value returned by sizeof. Marshal.SizeOf returns the
> size after the type has been marshaled, whereas sizeof returns the
> size as it has been allocated by the common language runtime,
> including any padding.
>
> Used to obtain the size in bytes for an unmanaged type****

Odds are that there is really no reason to need to obtain the size in bytes for a managed type, which is what you're doing.

*"Why do I need a Marshal for a fixed size variable?"*

You don't necessarily have to, if all you're looking for is the size of your local variable. You can simply call `var size = sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(short)`
which will return 4 and/or 2 respectively.

Comment: My idea was, for readability i could use the sizeof() for my fixed size variables.
Apparently not.